# Easy way to test TURN server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, webrtc, turn

I'm looking at this site, which is supposed to be table to test a TURN server ([according this this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28775122/5378216)).

plugin.temasys.com.sg/demo/samples/web/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/index.html

I put in my server info, but couldn't find anything to determine if the server is working. The ice candidates section looks the same even its there's no server chosen.

My TURN server is installed on Amazon EC2. I followed the install instructions from the coturn repository here:

github.com/coturn/coturn/blob/master/INSTALL

The following is what I get in my server when I do the command to start the TURN server, from [here](http://blog.knoldus.com/2013/10/24/configure-turn-server-for-webrtc-on-amazon-ec2/):

```
RFC 3489/5389/5766/5780/6062/6156 STUN/TURN Server
Version Coturn-4.2.1.2 'Monza'
0:
Max number of open files/sockets allowed for this process: 4096
0:
Due to the open files/sockets limitation,
max supported number of TURN Sessions possible is: 2000 (approximately)
0:

==== Show him the instruments, Practical Frost: ====

0: TLS supported
0: DTLS supported
0: AEAD supported
0: Redis supported
0: PostgreSQL supported
0: MySQL supported
0: MongoDB is not supported
0: OpenSSL compile-time version 0x1000106f: fresh enough
0: Default Net Engine version: 3 (UDP thread per CPU core)

=====================================================

0: Config file found: /usr/local/etc/turnserver.conf
0: Listener address to use: 172.31.43.176
0: Relay address to use: 172.31.43.176
0: Config file found: /usr/local/etc/turnserver.conf
0: Domain name:
0: Default realm: realm
0: Config file found: /usr/local/etc/turnuserdb.conf
0: WARNING: cannot find certificate file: turn_server_cert.pem (1)
0: WARNING: cannot start TLS and DTLS listeners because certificate file is not set properly
0: WARNING: cannot find private key file: turn_server_pkey.pem (1)
0: WARNING: cannot start TLS and DTLS listeners because private key file is not set properly
0: pid file created: /var/run/turnserver.pid
0: IO method (main listener thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: WARNING: I cannot support STUN CHANGE_REQUEST functionality because only one IP address is provided
0: Wait for relay ports initialization...
0:   relay 172.31.43.176 initialization...
0:   relay 172.31.43.176 initialization done
0: Relay ports initialization done
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IPv4. UDP listener opened on: 172.31.43.176:3478
0: Total UDP servers: 0
0: Total General servers: 1
0: turn server id=0 created
0: IPv4. TCP listener opened on : 172.31.43.176:3478
0: IO method (cli thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IPv4. CLI listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:5766
0: IO method (auth thread): epoll (with changelist)
```

It appears to be working, but how do I know? I apologize for my ignorance, I've been reading so many docs on this I can't keep track of it all.

EDIT: Well something is happening :)

I'm receiving these on my turn server now whenever use the site mentioned above:

```
64: ERROR: check_stun_auth: Cannot find credentials of user <ubuntu>
64: session 000000000000000004: realm <realm> user <ubuntu>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorised
```

EDIT 2: I removed the ubuntu portion, and am now receiving what appears to be successful responses. Still don't really know what it means, but it's a start :)

```
274: handle_udp_packet: New UDP endpoint: local addr 172.31.43.176:3478, remote addr 12.123.123.123:64064
274: session 000000000000000007: realm <realm> user <>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
274: handle_udp_packet: New UDP endpoint: local addr 172.31.43.176:3478, remote addr 12.123.123.123:64068
274: session 000000000000000008: realm <realm> user <>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
274: session 000000000000000007: realm <realm> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorised
274: session 000000000000000008: realm <realm> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorised
274: IPv4. Local relay addr: 172.31.43.176:56767
274: session 000000000000000007: new, realm=<realm>, username=<turnadm>, lifetime=600
274: session 000000000000000007: realm <realm> user <turnadm>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
274: IPv4. Local relay addr: 172.31.43.176:54363
274: session 000000000000000008: new, realm=<realm>, username=<turnadm>, lifetime=600
274: session 000000000000000008: realm <realm> user <turnadm>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
274: session 000000000000000007: realm <realm> user <turnadm>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
274: session 000000000000000008: realm <realm> user <turnadm>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:** A nice implementation in github.io taken from comment to another answer( choose "relay" in IceTransports value):

<kbd>[Test TURN Server](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/)</kbd>

---

run the below code in your browser console( firefox or chrome), replace `127.0.0.1` with your aws's external IP, that should give you the answer:

```
function checkTURNServer(turnConfig, timeout){ 

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

    setTimeout(function(){
        if(promiseResolved) return;
        resolve(false);
        promiseResolved = true;
    }, timeout || 5000);

    var promiseResolved = false
      , myPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection   //compatibility for firefox and chrome
      , pc = new myPeerConnection({iceServers:[turnConfig]})
      , noop = function(){};
    pc.createDataChannel("");    //create a bogus data channel
    pc.createOffer(function(sdp){
      if(sdp.sdp.indexOf('typ relay') > -1){ // sometimes sdp contains the ice candidates...
        promiseResolved = true;
        resolve(true);
      }
      pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
    }, noop);    // create offer and set local description
    pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){  //listen for candidate events
      if(promiseResolved || !ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate || !(ice.candidate.candidate.indexOf('typ relay')>-1))  return;
      promiseResolved = true;
      resolve(true);
    };
  });   
}

checkTURNServer({
    url: 'turn:127.0.0.1',
    username: 'test',
    credential: 'test'
}).then(function(bool){
    console.log('is my TURN server active? ', bool? 'yes':'no');
}).catch(console.error.bind(console));
```

**P.S**: make sure of two things, you pass aws's external ip as part of parameters when starting TURN server, make sure the port you are using is open for receiving and sending in aws settings.

Comment: Hi what kind of message should I be seeing if I tested the Turn Server on the webrtc.github.io link to see if the TURN server is working?

Comment: I tested my Coturn server with this code (I put it into my html page and modified the uri, username and password) and also with the webrtc.github.io. My server configuration was successful with github.io page, but this code always returned 'no'. I tried to debug this, but could not figure out why this code fails.

Comment: @mding5692, see the output of a successful test below.


`Time  Component  Type  Foundation  Protocol  Address  Port  Priority
0.010 1 host 0 udp addr.local 59895 126 | 32512 | 255
0.025 1 host 4 tcp addr.local 9 125 | 32704 | 255
0.026 2 host 0 udp addr.local 59896 126 | 32512 | 254
0.027 2 host 4 tcp addr.local 9 125 | 32704 | 254
11.207 Done`

Answer (score 23):

If you have a test app with WebRTC.

You can force the TURN on Firefox.

Tab: `about:config`

Search: `media.peerconnection.ice.relay_only`

Set it to `true`

At this moment Firefox only use TURN relay.

Comment: Is there any way to do same in chrome browser?